# Sharding: Shards with different properties?

Tags: gas-limit, block-interval, sharding

I am currently trying to get more into sharding but there's one question I haven't found any answer to yet.

Could sharding introduce shards with different properties? For example could Shard A have a block time of 10 seconds, a gas limit of 8 million and Shard B a block time of 4 seconds and a gas limit of 2 million?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it would be more complicated to implement.

See also https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQs#what-about-heterogeneous-sharding.

> ## What about heterogeneous sharding?
>
> Abstracting the execution engine or allowing multiple execution
>   engines to exist results in being able to have a different execution
>   engine for each shard. Due to Casper CBC being able to explore the
>   full [tradeoff
>   triangle](https://github.com/ethereum/cbc-casper/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-tradeoff-triangle),
>   it is possible to alter the parameters of the consensus engine for
>   each shard to be at any point of the triangle. However, CBC Casper has
>   not been implemented yet, and heterogeneous sharding is nothing more
>   than an idea at this stage; the specifics of how it would work has not
>   been designed nor implemented. Some shards could be optimized to have
>   fast finality and high throughput, which is important for applications
>   such as EFTPOS transactions, while maybe most could have a moderate or
>   reasonable amount each of finality, throughput and decentralization
>   (number of validating nodes), and applications that are prone to a
>   high fault rate and thus require high security, such as torrent
>   networks, privacy focused email like Proton mail, etc., could optimize
>   for a high decentralization, low finality and high throughput, etc.
>   See also https://twitter.com/VladZamfir/status/932320997021171712 and
>   https://ethresear.ch/t/heterogeneous-sharding/1979/2.